# Allusion in the quotes or not?

Tags: quotations, literary-device, allusion

> 1. Between 1980 and 1983, the government had imprisoned and executed so many high-school and college students that we no longer dared to talk politics.
> 2. [The Iranian National Anthem] had been forbidden and replaced by the new government's Islamic hymn.

According to the dictionary, an allusion is reference to someone or something that is known from history, literature, religion, politics, sports, science, or another branch of culture.

I believe that these two quotes contain allusion because they referred to Islamic government in Iran.

Am I correct?

Comment: Hi sds.  As far as I can see, these really have nothing to do with "allusion".  Just to clarify the nature of your question, are you learning English, or are you a native English speaker?  If you simply "don't use the name" of something (replacing it with say "her" or "them" or "it" .. that has nothing to do with allusion. For example, "John has a red car. He also has a blue car." In the second sentence the "He" has nothing to do with "allusion". "Allusion" is when you "hint" at something.

Answer (score 1):

Allusion is an *indirect* reference to something.

*This is the worst scandal since Watergate* is not an allusion.

*Presidents have gotten in trouble for covert dirty tricks* is an **allusion** to Watergate, because it's indirect.

Neither requires quotation marks.